# Old version of jQuery added automatically to CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, jquery, cloudpage

After struggling for a week with a CloudPage that wasn't working as expected, I finally noticed that the editor somehow adds an old version of jQuery to every CloudPage after publishing it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to prevent it from doing that - any tips?

This is what I found in all my CloudPages after publishing them and checking the Console, and it's not visible in the editor in CloudPages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I will appreciate any workaround on either preventing this or overwriting this with a higher version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that it's not enough if you switch to "Code View" in the new Content Builder in CloudPages.

Here are two valid workarounds that I have been able to find:

1. If you're working with an existing CloudPage built in the new Content Builder and for any reason, you are not able to recreate it on a new landing page, you will need to overwrite the old version of jQuery with a new one, by inserting the higher version of jQuery at the bottom of the CloudPage. Not the best, but works.
2. If you can or if you are creating a new CloudPage from scratch, you will need to create it in the Classic Editor, and select Code View when creating the landing page - that way Marketing Cloud won't insert anything apart from the tracking code:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is added to make some of the WYSIWYG added components work. If you are not using smart capture or any of the other 'gears', I would suggest creating the cloud page in 'Code View' or creating a code resource instead. Both of these options will prevent jQuery from being added.

Comment: Hi @Tyler, creating the page in Code View didn’t help - it still added jQuery, but I will check whether creating it in the Classic editor will be any better - thanks!